# Intermittently missing Posted bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using minimal API in ASP.Net 7 Core to send an array of bytes from my client to my server.  2 out of 3 times this works and I get bytes on the server.  But 1 of 3 times there are 0 bytes.

Here is my code (cleaned somewhat to simplify)

```
var client = new HttpClient();
byte[] arr = AnArrayThatIs100PercentneverEmpty();
Log.Information($"Sending {arr.Length} bytes");
client.PostAsync(url, new ByteArrayContent(arr));
```

On the receiveing side I have:

```
app.MapPost("/v1/agent_relay/call_result/{company_id}/{guid}",  (HttpContext context, string company_id, string guid) =>
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                Log.Information($"Post call_result for {company_id} {guid} {ms.Length}");
            ...  
            }
```

Any idea why sometimes the bytes are received and sometimes they are not?  I feel like slippery streams are causing issues somehow, but do not see it, as the `arr` really is an array of bytes that has a non-zero length when I send it.

Comment: you've called an async method there and don't wait for it (CopyToAsync(ms))... so maybe that's the issue?  It's going to happen, it's just that it's not blocking your log call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was that CopyToAsync is async (duh) so I needed to await it and make the response async as well.  Here is the solution:

```
app.MapPost("/v1/agent_relay/call_result/{company_id}/{guid}",  async (HttpContext context, string company_id, string guid) =>
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                Log.Information($"Post call_result for {company_id} {guid} {ms.Length}");
            ...  
            }
```

*Ok, I simply posted this to ChatGPT and it told me the answer.  The thing is scary/wonderful*

Comment: GPT is just a powerful generative statistical machine, i would not rely on it on complex questions, requiring accurate logical reasoning. async/await is everywhere nowadays in .NET, so not surprised GPT found the answer